# No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:database.db

Tags: java, sqlite, servlets, jdbc

I want to use SQLite with my Java Servlet Server. So I wrote a singleton database Controller which I initialize in my `init` function inside my servlet. When I reach the following line

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

I'm getting this Exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:database.db
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at Controller.Database.SQLiteDataBase.getInstance(SQLiteDataBase.java:22)
    at Controller.Servlets.login.loginController.init(loginController.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1090)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:417)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I tested to get a connection in a new project outside my servlet Application and everything worked fine.

I'm using Eclipse Jee Oxygen and used Add External JARs.. to add sqlite-jdbc-3.21.0.jar

What can I do to fix this problem? I already tried absolute and relative paths to the .db file.

Comment: You got this error on deployed project inside tomcat? is it a war? inside the war there's the sqllite jar?

Comment: sorry im new to java / programming i dont really understand. im getting this error on my console

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119328/why-do-i-need-to-call-class-forname-in-tomcat-web-application-even-if-i-use-a-jd

Comment: You should either put the Connector/J lib in the Tomcat `lib` folder, or - if deployed with your application - you need to explicitly load the driver using `Class.forName`, as automatic driver loading doesn't work for drivers not on the system classpath. However, you shouldn't be using `DriverManager`, configure a datasource instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the sqlite-jdbc-3.21.0.jar to your server classpath, you can put it in the lib folder of your tomcat server, or you can put this jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder of your project.

Comment: sadly doesnt change anything (screenshot maybe i did it wrong https://image.prntscr.com/image/rE9lgF4LQCWUIB4yNPDQ-A.png )

Comment: Could you plase try adding this code `Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");` before the line `Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);`

Comment: Also could you please share the URL string that you're using to establish the connection

Comment: String url = "jdbc:sqlite:database.db";
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

Comment: after adding clss.forname... im getting java.sql.SQLException: opening db: 'database.db': Zugriff verweigert (german for access denied)

Comment: when i initialize my controller outside of servlets everything is working fine even w/o class forname etc :(

Comment: It could be then a problem on the path of your database could you please try using an absolute path to your database to see if it works
 `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\path\\to\\your\\database\\file\\yourdatabasefile.db");`

Comment: its working thanks! any tipps where i should put my file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164215/discussion-between-cesar-loachamin-and-barney-stinson).

Comment: Great! I definitely I don’t put my dB file in the project path I woul create a folder like /opt/data or C:\data if you mind if that solves the problem could you please select this as the answer for your question